# How can I fix 1064 error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing this error while trying to join these two tables

A Database Error Occurred  Error Number: 1064

**Error :**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order, customer WHERE order.customer_id=customer.customer_id' at
>   line 2

**Query :**

```
SELECT order.order_id,order.order_total,
customer.first_name,customer.last_name FROM order, customer WHERE
order.customer_id=customer.customer_id;
```

**Filename:**

> D:\xampp\htdocs\compulectronix2\system\database\DB_driver.php  Line
>   Number: 330

Comment: Try to do this FROM order INNER JOIN customer ON order.customer_id = customer.customer_id

Comment: It's not working @Miladinovic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ORDER" is a reserved word in SQL. You must quote it with backquotes:

```
SELECT 
    `order`.order_id,
    `order`.order_total,
    customer.first_name, customer.last_name 
FROM `order`, customer 
WHERE `order`.customer_id=customer.customer_id
```

[List of reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

Every language has some reserve words we also called those as keyword.  We can't create variable with those reserve word.

Here your table name is 'order', order is a reserve word in mysql so it is generating en error. You have two choice

1. As practice don't  use mysql reserve word as table name so you can rename the table.
2. If you don't want to rename table then put quote with table name
   and user this way

   ```
   SELECT 
       `order`.order_id,
       `order`.order_total,
       customer.first_name, customer.last_name 
   FROM `order`, customer 
   WHERE `order`.customer_id=customer.customer_id
   ```

Hope it will help you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

WITH JOIN

```
SELECT `order`.`order_id`, `order`.`order_total`, `customer`.`first_name`, `customer`.`last_name`
FROM `order`
JOIN `customer` ON
`order`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`customer_id`;
```

WITHOUT JOIN

```
SELECT `order`.`order_id`, `order`. `order_total`,
`customer`.`first_name`, `customer`.`last_name` 
FROM `order`, `customer` 
WHERE `order`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`customer_id`;
```